# Is there any service for Linux Virtual Private Server comparsion of providers?

Tags: vps, dedicated-hosting, comparison

I'm going to buy Linux Virtual Private Server, but I would like to compare offers that hosting companies have. I would like to compare servers memory, disk, bandwidth, cpu and price per month. So far I have found manually searching that godaddy.com has pretty good offers, but I would like to compare more hosting companies to get best offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SquareCompare](http://squarecompare.com/vps-hosting/) offers a comparison service with a variety of comparison criteria (advertised with them while working for a VPS hosting company).

Note: "Virtual dedicated" isn't a common term (remember seeing it first over at Media Temple - it isn't accurate at all if the server resides on shared hardware) so you might get better results if you're asking about/searching for "virtual private server" comparison services.

Answer (score 1):

I found site http://www.lowendbox.com/, its not comparison, but it has a lot of blog posts about very cheap VPS hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this list of [Cheap VPS Hosting provider](http://www.thewebhostingdir.com/vps-hosting/cheap-vps-server-hosting/)'s list. They don't have any straight forward link to compare all the plans, but you still get a very good comparison of various known - unknown VPS providers.